# How can we integrate the B2B endpoint based on eBXML with the Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi, b2b, ebxml

How can we integrate the B2B endpoint based on eBXML with the Node.js application? Client has given us 1 cpa , 1 sendurl , ebXML request and response files , 1 endurl to listen the response

How to integrate B2B application with node.js application
The client has given as url to send the ebXML payload to this url

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.